# Filter backbone collection by attribute value

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a defined model and a collection:

```
var Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: 1,
        h: 1,
        color: "black"
    }

});

var Boxes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Box
});
```

When the collection is populated with the models, I need a new Boxes collection made out of Box models that have a specific color attribute contained in the complete collection, I do it this way:

```
var sorted = boxes.groupBy(function(box) {
    return box.get("color");
});


var red_boxes = _.first(_.values(_.pick(sorted, "red")));

var red_collection = new Boxes;

red_boxes.each(function(box){
    red_collection.add(box);
});

console.log(red_collection);
```

This works, but I find it a bit complicated and unefficient. Is there a way of doing this same thing in a more simple way?

Here is the code I described: http://jsfiddle.net/HB88W/1/

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I like returning a new instance of the collection. This makes these filtering methods chainable (`boxes.byColor("red").bySize("L")`, for example).

```js
var Boxes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Box,

    byColor: function (color) {
        filtered = this.filter(function (box) {
            return box.get("color") === color;
        });
        return new Boxes(filtered);
    }
});

var red_boxes = boxes.byColor("red")
```

Comment: Will this change cid in model?

Comment: filterBy: function(attribute, value) {
    filtered = this.filter(function(box) {
      return box.get(attribute) === value;
      });
    return new Boxes(filtered);
  }

Comment: Why return a `new Boxes()`. I would write

    var Boxes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Box,
      byColor: function(color) {
        return this.filter(function(box) {
          return box.get("color") === color;
        });
      }
    });

Comment: Is this using filter from Underscore.js?

Comment: Marcoslhc: that won't return a Backbone collection but an array of models

Comment: Adding two related and interesting links:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1519/rendering-a-filtered-backbonecollection

https://github.com/p3drosola/Backbone.VirtualCollection

Comment: @janetsmith No, it won't change the cid of the model. That would only happen if you initialized a new one or cloned it.

Comment: you may want to declare the `filtered` variable in its scope (`byColor` function)

Comment: @paniclater I would assume so since Backbone is based on Underscore.

Answer (score 48):

See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

```
var red_boxes = boxes.where({color: "red"});

var red_collection = new Boxes(red_boxes);
```

Comment: `where` returns an array of the collection, rather than a collection object.

Comment: This is a great solution, unless you are forced into using an older version of Backbone that does not have "where" implemented yet.