# Shorten an array or collection with an array of fields

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

**Scenario**:

- you have an array,
- you have an array of *some* ids (eg: [1,3]),
- you want to get a shortened array.

I cannot find how to do so if not in the lengthy way:

```
_.filter(... function (id) { return id==1 || id==3 })
```

**Question**: does such `someMethod1` exist in underscore.js?

```
var frdsArr = 
[
 {id: 1, name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
 {id: 2, name: 'larry', age: 50}, 
 {id: 3, name: 'curly', age: 60}
];


var goodFrdsArr = _.someMethod1( frdsArr, 'id', [1, 3] );
/*
goodFrdsArr is [
 {id: 1, name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
 {id: 3, name: 'curly', age: 60}
];
*/
```

---

The same question with backbone.js: what about `someMethod2`?

```
var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var FriendsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Friend
});

var friendsCollection = new FriendsCollection( frdsArr );
var goodFriendsCollection = friendsCollection.someMethod2( 'id', [1,3] );
/*
goodFriendsCollection contains 2 instances of Friend Models
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have found a suitable function, you can extend Underscore with [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) to simplify later calls. For example, you could create `_.restrict` to match your `_.someMethod1` signature:

```
_.mixin({
    // filter a list on an attribute having to match a list of values
    // _.indexOf accepts an optional isSorted argument so let's pass it
    restrict: function(list, attr, values, isSorted) {

        return _.filter(list, function(obj) {
            return _.indexOf(values, obj[attr], isSorted) !== -1;
        });

    }
});

var goodFrdsArr = _.restrict(frdsArr, 'id', [1, 3]);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cf0qs5gh/ for a demo

With this setup, you can modify `Backbone.Collection`'s prototype to give all your collections this new capacity (more or less taken from the Backbone source code):

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.restrict = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift(this.models);
    return _.restrict.apply(_, args);
};

var friendsCollection = new Backbone.Collection(frdsArr);
var goodfriends = c.restrict('id', [1, 3]);  //an array with 2 models
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/cf0qs5gh/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var frdsArr = 
[
 {id: 1, name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
 {id: 2, name: 'larry', age: 50}, 
 {id: 3, name: 'curly', age: 60}
];
var filteredIDs = [1,3];
var filteredFrnds = _.filter(frdsArr, function(frnd){
return _.contains(filteredIDs, frnd.id);
})
console.log(filteredFrnds);
```

Make use of ***[filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)*** and ***[contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains)***

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ze228vgr/)***

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  the side column suggests a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22263895/2841279).