# Performance on shortening an array with an array of attributes, with underscore

Tags: underscore.js

The same question:
you have an array of attributes
you want to shorten the long array to get entries matching those attributes.

I see two solutions ( with [map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263895/2841279) and [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616368/2841279) ) here.

```
1.   _.map(     ... function () { .findWhere  } );
2.   _.filter ( ... function () { .contains   } );
```

I put both into this [ [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Luwohsy/3/)  ]

The comparison on the number of iteration is certain, but which runs faster?

Comment: Well @PraveenPrasannan already made a [test](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27616368/2841279)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already there in underscore.js documentation, but hidden.

**map**

> _.map(list, iteratee, [context]) Alias: collect  Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation
>   function (iteratee). If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's
>   arguments will be (value, key, list).

**filter**

> _.filter(list, predicate, [context]) Alias: select  Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a
>   truth test (predicate).

**contains**

> _.contains(list, value) Alias: include  Returns true if the value is present in the list. Uses indexOf internally, if list is an Array.

**findWhere**

> _.findWhere(list, properties)  Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in
>   properties.
>
> If no match is found, or if list is empty, undefined will be returned.

Map produce a new array. So it needs to work background for the memory allocation and references while looping, whereas filter will loop and return the reference for those item passed truth test.
Contains return boolean, whereas findwhere retrun the first matched item. more and more background work. 
Performance is determined not just by the number of times the loop works, but the total amount of work done. :)

Please check the results yourself : ***[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/underscoreadqwer34r13)***